# cmake error: Could not find QCA2

Tags: makefile, cmake

Encountered the following message while cmake-ing libjreen on Mac.

```
$ cmake ..
-- checking for module 'qca2'
--   package 'qca2' not found
CMake Error at /opt/local/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:91 (MESSAGE):
  Could NOT find QCA2 (missing: QCA2_LIBRARIES QCA2_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/local/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:252 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  cmake/FindQCA2.cmake:44 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:22 (FIND_PACKAGE)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

How do I go on about installing qca2?

**Update** I have installed qca through macports without any luck. It seems I would need libqca2-devel which is not present on macports. How do I install libqca2-devel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this got solved.
I had to install qca2 from source so that cmake could pick it up